# nested resource controller laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In laravel 4 i would like to have a nested controller.

I have read the documentation but didn't find any explanation on how to do it.

Supose that in a app i have some articles and each article have his own set of comments. I would like to be able to get all comment of a specific article by accessing a URL like this.

http://myapp.com/articles/5/comments

I have created a commentsController, but i don't know how to correctly get the article id from the url, so i can pass it to all my CRUD methods in my controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in route.php

```
Route::resource('articles.comments','commentsController');
```

in controller

```
public function show($articleId, $comment) {}

public function create($articleId) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure nested resource controllers are the way to go.... Here is what I would do.

```
Route::resource('articles','articlesController');
Route::get('articles/{$id}/comments','articlesController@comments');
```

Then in your controller

```
public function comments($id) {

}
```

Comment: Although this would work, it would only provide a single route, removing the benefit of using a resource. Your suggested way you would need to manually add all the required GET, POST, PATCH & PUT routes..... messy!